# Inverse of $\ln(e^x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, inverse, inverse-function

so the whole concept about inverses is a little foggy.

Say you have function $f(x)=\ln(e^x-3)$ and you want to know the inverse function, then:

> $$\ln(e^x-3) = y$$
>     $$e^x-3 = e^y$$
>     $$e^x = e^y + 3$$
>     $$x=\ln(e^y+3)$$
>     $$ f^{-1}(x)=\ln(e^x+3)$$

So my confusion comes here, the range of the original function is (-inf. to + inf), so that must be the domain of the inverse function, correct? So if we look at the domain of the inverse function by setting $e^x + 3$ to $0$, it's $\ln(-3) = x$ which is undefined and argh... what do we even have to check and define in cases of inverse functions and how should we make sure its correct... would love some clarity...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define $\ln \left( e^x - 3 \right)$ at $x = 0$? What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: Your range for the original function is not right.

Comment: @ZacharySelk fixed, thanks!

Comment: Range of $\ln(e^x-3)$ is all reals so for inverse, $x$ can be any real. $e^x+3$ cannot be zero but why does it matter?

Comment: Domain of $f$ is $(\ln 3, \infty)$ and the range is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Oh man! How did I mess that one up... alright but how does the range make sense for the domain of the inverse function...?

Comment: @user472288 based on your work, the inverse function you have obtained has domain as $\Bbb{R}$ (because $e^x+3 >0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$), which is also the range of $f$.

Comment: @AnuragA how can the domain of a log function be valid for any real numbers? I thought log functions can only contain numbers from $>0$

Comment: @user472288: because under the log you have $e^x+3$ which is always positive regardless of what the value of $x$ is.

Comment: @user472288 It depends on the quantity whose log is being taken. For example, for $f(x)=\ln(x^2+1)$, the expression $x^2+1>0$ so basically for any $x$ the quantity whose log is being taken is positive.

Comment: Okay I missed the part where $x$ is the exponent inside the log function..... thanks guys I really appreciate it. Solved :)! Side question: Any idea on what we should do if the range of the original function does not equal the domain of the inverse function?

Comment: @user472288 that cannot happen.

Comment: How would it even be considered an inverse in such a case?

Comment: Well say you have a square root, and you search for the inverse, its going to be a parabola in which case you have to define the domain of the functions. I was thinking about the other way around (range), but I guess its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right that the range of $f$ is from negative infinity to positive infinity.
But $f^{-1}$ is also defined from negative to positive infinity, there is no problem in that since $e^x+3>0$ for all $x$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\log$ is increasing and $\exp$ is nonnegative, hence $\log(e^x+3) > \log(3) > 0.$

Also, your original function is defined only when $e^x-3 > 0$ or $x > \log 3.$

Comment: Yes.. but the range of the original function can go from neg infinity to positive infinity, how does that work for the inverse function whose domain (since its a log function) can only be greater than 0?

Comment: $e^x$ is defined for all $x.$

Comment: ... and $e^x+3 > 0$  for *all* $x$, so no matter what $x$ is, the argument of the logarithm is positive. So the inverse function's domain is the whole real line.